# Get select element from a form

Tags: php, html, phalcon, volt

I am beginner when it comes to Phalcon framework and his Volt engine but i would really like to learn it. I am following their documentation and i am currently on their INVO project.

And they have a database of products, and those products have like a type (5-Vegetables, 6-Fruit). So when i list all the products, it displays all the data about that product and it gives you the link to "edit" that data for that specific product. So when i click on "edit" i want to open like a html form that will contain already filled fields with data from that specific product.

This is the form class that they use to create a form for products:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Forms\Form;
use Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text;
use Phalcon\Forms\Element\Hidden;
use Phalcon\Forms\Element\Select;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\PresenceOf;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Numericality;

class ProductsForm extends Form
{
    /**
     * Initialize the products form
     *
     * @param null $entity
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function initialize($entity = null, $options = array())
    {
        if (isset($options['edit'])) {
            $element = new Text("id");
            $this->add($element->setLabel("Id"));
        } else {
            $this->add(new Hidden("id"));
        }

        $name = new Text("name");
        $name->setLabel("Name");
        $name->setFilters(array('striptags', 'string'));
        $name->addValidators(
            array(
                new PresenceOf(
                    array(
                        'message' => 'Name is required'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        $this->add($name);

        $type = new Select(
            'profilesId',
            ProductTypes::find(),
            array(
                'using' => array('id', 'name'),
                'useEmpty' => true,
                'emptyText' => '...',
                'emptyValue' => ''
            )
        );
        $this->add($type);

        $price = new Text("price");
        $price->setLabel("Price");
        $price->setFilters(array('float'));
        $price->addValidators(
            array(
                new PresenceOf(
                    array(
                        'message' => 'Price is required'
                    )
                ),
                new Numericality(
                    array(
                        'message' => 'Price is required'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        $this->add($price);
    }
}
```

This is the action from the controller:

```
/**
 * Shows the view to "edit" an existing product
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    if (!$this->request->isPost()) {
        $product = Products::findFirstById($id);
        if (!$product) {
            $this->flash->error("Product was not found");
            return $this->forward("products/index");
        }

        $this->view->form = new ProductsForm($product, array('edit' => true));
    }
}
```

And this is my edit.volt view file:

```
{{ form("products/whatever") }}

<h2>Search products</h2>

<fieldset>

    {% for element in form %}
        <div class="control-group">
            {{ element.label(['class': 'control-label']) }}
            <div class="controls">{{ element }}</div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="control-group">
        {{ submit_button("Edit", "class": "btn btn-primary") }}
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Now when i click on a specific product i get this:
[Edit screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeVcy.png)

As you can see... everything except the select tag has been already filled and that works fine... its just that one select that doesn't get selected. :(
I mean i can click the dropdown menu and it does show me the data... but i want it to be already selected like everything else is.

So my question is, can i add (and how to do it if its possible) like an if statement inside my edit.volt that will go like "if the next element is a select element, just select the value that is already in the database", like in that screen, if its bell pepper then 5-Vegetables should already be selected... then if you want you can change it and save it... but i just want it to already be selected.

I apologize for the long post.

Comment: Your code looks fine. The name of your select input  (`profilesId`), is that also the name of the profile column in your `product` model ?

Comment: @Timothy No it isn't. In my products model it is called $product_types_id, and that is a foreign key to another model called ProductTypes ($id) (that model contains just id and name for types: like for example id:5 name:Vegetables). I used Phalcon Dev Tools to create my models and it created it with those names, because thats how those columns are named in the database (btw: this is from the Phalcon documentation tutorial... i use their stuff, because im just trying to learn this, but apparently i'm too dumb even for that :( ).

Comment: @Timothy  , the only thing i did was for edit.volt, because they didn't provide the code for that file, so i just copied that from another file. I figured i could use it since i just need a form and it will populate with the data it was given

Comment: Then change the name of your select element from `profilesId` to `product_type_id`

Comment: @Timothy thanks, it works now. Now im wondering why did they even named it "profilesId", it doesnt make any sense :/. Oh well, anyway thank you for the answer.

Comment: Mind if I write this up in an answer?  So other users won't need to struggle on this. :)

Comment: @Blitva, they probably named it profilesId because they were using column mapping somewhere. Also make sure to accept and upvote Timothy's answer below as it helped you solve the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Phalcon to auto assign database values to your form, you need to make sure your form elements have the same name as your `Products` columns (~database columns).
Otherwise Phalcon can't know how to map your `Products` values to their correct form elements.

Controller:

```
$product = Products::findFirstById($id);
// ...
$this->view->form = new ProductsForm($product, array('edit' => true));
```

Form:

```
$type = new Select(
    'product_type_id', // was previously "profilesId"
    ProductTypes::find(),
    array(
        'using' => array('id', 'name'),
        'useEmpty' => true,
        'emptyText' => '...',
        'emptyValue' => ''
    )
);
```

As you mentioned in the comments, your `Products` model doesn't have a `profilesId` column but instead a `product_type_id` column. Therefor you should rename your `Select` element from `profilesId` to `product_type_id`.